# How can I name a $(a+x)\cdot b$ function

Tags: functions, terminology

I'm looking for a name to identify functions like $f(x) = (x + a)\cdot b$.

Does this kind of function have a specific name (like "affine" for $a\cdot x+b$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are (almost) the same as **affine functions**, because
$$(x+a)\cdot b= b\cdot x+a\cdot b$$
and, if $a\ne 0$,
$$a\cdot x+b=(x+b/a)\cdot a\,.$$
By the latter distinguished value $0$ of the multiplier, we don't get *constant* functions in the given form, only the constant $0$.

So, we could call your functions '*nonconstant affine or zero*'.

Comment: I was a bit confuse by the (almost). What you mean is that these **are** all affine functions, but not all affine functions can be written in this form (the nonzero constant functions cannot).

Comment: I have updated my answer. Only nonzero constants are missing.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I just wanted to know if a specific name exists 'cause I actually have to differentiate ax+b from (a+x)*b.